# How to merge several cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some problems with excel and VBA, in that don't know have much knowledge. I copied text from pdf and it's awful.
I have cells which contain some text.
The problem is that the text from one paragraph is broken down over several cells. At the beginning of each paragraph is a word in bold (e.g. **CLR.**) which describes the rest of the text. As such, it defines where each paragraph should start. How I can merge these cells into one?

I see [image: This original image]]

I want [image: This formatting]

Comment: How do you identify which lines to merge and from where to start a new line?

Comment: I want to start new line with bold statement. In my screen is CLR, CLI, Razor and etc. Got it?

Comment: Which is the logic behind this?

Comment: So, if I'll have 500+ cells and I should concatenate all this cells, it will so hard make by hands

Comment: What you want to do is concatenate, not merge

Comment: I would recommend opening the `.pdf` file in word before copying text across to Excel. This seems to help with the format issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MergeText()

    Dim strMerged$, r&, j&, i&

    r = 1
    Do While True
        If Cells(r, 1).Characters(1, 1).Font.Bold Then
            strMerged = "": strMerged = Cells(r, 1)
            r = r + 1
            While (Not Cells(r, 1).Characters(1).Font.Bold) And Len(Cells(r, 1)) > 0
                strMerged = strMerged & Cells(r, 1)
                r = r + 1
            Wend
            i = i + 1: Cells(i, 2) = strMerged
            Cells(i, 2).Characters(1, InStr(1, strMerged, ".", vbTextCompare)).Font.Bold = True
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify (if needed) and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, Count As Long
    Dim str As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change sheet name if needed

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

            If (UCase(Left(.Range("A" & i), 1)) <> Left(.Range("A" & i), 1)) And UCase(Left(.Range("A" & i - 1), 1)) = Left(.Range("A" & i - 1), 1) Then

                Count = 0

                For j = 1 To Len(.Range("A" & i - 1))

                    If .Range("A1").Characters(j, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold" Then
                        Count = Count + 1
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next j

                str = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value & " " & .Range("A" & i).Value

                With .Range("A" & i - 1)
                    .Value = str
                    .Font.Bold = False

                    With .Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Count).Font
                        .FontStyle = "Bold"
                    End With

                End With

                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

            ElseIf (UCase(Left(.Range("A" & i), 1)) <> Left(.Range("A" & i), 1)) And UCase(Left(.Range("A" & i - 1), 1)) <> Left(.Range("A" & i - 1), 1) Then

                str = .Range("A" & i - 1).Value & " " & .Range("A" & i).Value

                With .Range("A" & i - 1)
                    .Value = str
                    .Font.Bold = False
                End With

                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well work!
But one thing: If we have bold cell, I mean our cell have bold properties, then all string will have bold format. But I need bold only my Key-word, not all string. Do you realized me?