# How cut a substring?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of string which can contain italic font. I want to copy this string with this font. In each new string I have bold word

Example: [image]

BIG STRING: [image]

I tried:

```
Public Function GetDefinition(ByVal rngText As Range) As String
Dim theCell As Range
Set theCell = rngText.Cells(1, 1)

For I = 1 To Len(theCell.Value)
    If theCell.Characters(I, 1).Font.Bold = False Then
        If theCell.Characters(I + 1, 1).Text = " " Then
            theChar = theCell.Characters(I, 1).Text
            Else
            theChar = theCell.Characters(I, 1).Text
        End If
        Results = Results & theChar
    End If
Next I
GetDefinition = Results
End Function
```

Comment: Want to get column C, can see above my attempt

Comment: You have data in column A and you need to remove the Bold part and paste the string in column C?

Comment: yeap, but I should save italic font

Comment: is there a chance to have Bold characters in different parts of the string or only add the beginning?

Comment: bold words can be only at the beginning

Comment: @Anthony14 do the bold words end always with a dot? because there you can split the string.

Comment: yes, bold words end with a dot, but I should save italic font in my text

Comment: @Anthony14 then try the code in my answer.

Comment: the italics appears many time?

Comment: yes, the italics can be several times in each string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge several cells using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700110/how-to-merge-several-cells-using-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, PositionOfDot As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find last row of column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Loop from row 1 to lastrow
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            'Copy paste from column A to C keeping formatting
            .Range("A" & i).Copy .Range("C" & i)
            'Find the position of "."
            PositionOfDot = InStr(1, .Range("A" & i), ".")
            'Delete characters starting from the first one up to PositionOfDot+1
            .Range("C" & i).Characters(1, PositionOfDot + 1).Delete

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: works good. But I have a question, I noticed, that if string big, it doesnt work ( I attached screen with example). Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: 255 character limit

Comment: I tried, but i need to save italic font and cut bold at the beginning

Comment: @Anthony14 what to you mean by 255 character limit? the code code the whole cell (value & formatting) and them remove the BOLD pieces. i can not understand where is the issue

Answer (score 0):

If your bold string always ends with a dot this will do it for you:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function GetDefinition(ByVal rngText As Range) As String

    Dim SplitBold As Variant

    SplitBold = Split(rngText, ". ")
    GetDefinition = Trim(SplitBold(1))

End Function
```